Laravel / Pusher, broadcasting/auth, Broadcast channel not working correct
I'm trying to use one Server (Backend) as source to transmit data to private channels.
Trying as Client another place/machine (mob app / , server/client), connect to private channel to be able to read data transmit by Backend.
We are using Laravel 10 and Puscher.
Auth for priv channel as Backend and client on same machine is working fine.
Main problem is that Clint from outside can't authorize, getting 403 Forbidden
Setup:
"php": "^8.1",
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
"laravel/framework": "^10.10",
"laravel/sanctum": "^3.3",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.8",
"pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2"
To be able to test the flow we setup 2 servers:
1 Main 'Backend' server in different place different machine different URL
2 Second as 'Client' server in different place different machine different URL

on main 'Backend' we setup channel:

Broadcast::channel('private.xxx.{id}', function ($deviceId) {
    return true;
});


we use Postman too test it:
setup POST, put URL https://backend_domain/broadcasting/auth',
setup prams as: 'socket_id' as '1.2' as for test and 'channel_name' as 'private.xxx.2'

Is working fine, getting, answer:
{
"auth": "08d916334e5f9da04213:6f12dca7d0dd8662562e0518a51c58f991c0f642de2903760e1c207efdbc8814"
}
Now the main stuff: I know that larval and Echo is adding prefix as 'private-' to the name of channel.
When under the main 'Backend' server we setup echo client:
window.Echo.private('private.xxx.2')
    .listen('.xxx', (e) => {
        console.log('Priv Message received:', e);

    })
    .subscribed(() => {
        console.log('Subscribed to channel xxx');
    })
    .error((error) => {
        console.error('Error subscribing:', error);
    });


we can read success information (so main server is using the channel and go through auth there)
payload in Network as auth we can see sent information as:

socket_id: 189861.737011
channel_name: private-private.xxx.2


so in same machine all is working fine and in payload request we can see full correct name as [private-private.xxx.2]

Now we do the same in 2 machine 'Client'
-setup:
const authorizationHeader = `Bearer ${token}`;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '123...',
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true,
    authEndpoint: 'https://backend_domain/broadcasting/auth', 
    auth: {
        headers: {
            Authorization: authorizationHeader 
        }
    }
});


we tell to this client all data to Pusher he need to know (we can easily connect too normal Channels so data are correct)
we put the special auth URL so Client know where to send question to auth
we setup client as:

window.Echo.private('private.xxx.2')
    .listen('.xxx', (e) => {
        console.log('Priv Message received:', e);

    })
    .subscribed(() => {
        console.log('Subscribed to channel xxx');
    })
    .error((error) => {
        console.error('Error subscribing:', error);
    });


exactly same like Main backend previously, and effect is: 403 Forbidden
console error, network payload data are:

socket_id: 189876.728811
channel_name: private-private.xxx.2


the same like early This is the main Problem to solve how to connect it.

What is the most strange think, and the simples check:
1 use postman with data : 'socket_id' as '1.2' as for test and 'channel_name' as 'private.xxx.2'

is working superb (see that we are asking without prefix 'private-'
the channel setup is Broadcast::channel('private.xxx.{id}', function ($deviceId)
2 use postman with data : 'socket_id' as '1.2' as for test and 'channel_name' as 'private-private.xxx.2' Like it should be from beginning and same way like other outside Client is asking also in payload
is not working we are getting 403 Forbidden

Question way ?
Debug:
I put another channel to check naming:
Broadcast::channel('private-private.xxx.{id}', function ($deviceId) {
    return true;
});


use postman like it should be: channel_name =  private-private.xxx.1
answer 403 Forbidden (so any channel is not working, for I want to check which channel is working or giving 403, and I put at end of the channels.php stop script Echo "TEST STOP"; die; and I get it on the screen.
So the flow like going inside channels.php is working fine.

Postman is working with : private.xxx.1
Don't work with : private-private.xxx.1 (which is the main problem because outside client use such name in payload)
Please help me. Was 3 days on it already

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why did you rollback the edit that was fixing spelling mistakes?

Did not know, as new user, the options, i hope now it is oks ;p Thank fro corrections

Problem has been solved.
First of all, when the inquiry comes from outside, we are not authorized in any way and immediately when the channel is 'private-' the system returns a 403.
The default web guard in the system is responsible for checking this.
Even if you send yourself a token, it has to be handled and web guard is not designed for this.
The solution is to write your own Guard that will verify the appropriate access rights to the channel, e.g.:
Broadcast::channel('device.{deviceId}', function ($deviceId) {

$token = request()->header('Authorization');
if (strpos($token, 'Bearer ') === 0) {
    $token = substr($token, 7);
}

// some xxx logic
if ($xxx->replaced == 0){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}}, ['guards' => ['device']]); //<-- this line is the most importand , by defult its ['guards' => ['web']] and you dont see it

Best Regards Artur
I hope that this help someone i invest 4 days in all kind of test to get it work ;p
